# Inconsistent Results from Elastic Index

Tags: elasticsearch

I have two elastic search indexes, to the best of my understanding these indexes have an identical setup, apart from their name. One index has ~1.7 million documents, the other has 8.

The documents have the following structure:

```
{
    _index: "locations",
    _type: "location",
    _id: "Royal Leamington Spa",
    _version: 1,
    found: true,
    _source: {
        name: "Royal Leamington Spa",
        coordinate: {
            lat: 52.29156048773691,
            lon: -1.5343337101975745
        }
    }
}
```

I am querying both with the following:

```
POST http://<server>/locations/location/_search
{
    "from": 0,
    "size": 10,
    "sort": [
    {
        "_score": {}
    }
    ],
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "name": {
                "type": "phrase_prefix",
                "query": "Royal Le"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The larger of the two indexes returns no results, but the smaller index returns the document I was expecting. What causes the difference in result and how can I query the larger index in a way that will return results for "Royal Leamington Spa"?

Comment: And we should assume that the larger index DOES have the documents? Also, these two indices have the same mapping (including custom analyzers and such)? Can you pinpoint the document from the larger index and see how it differs from the one in the smaller index? Use `fielddata_fields:["name"]` on both indices for that specific document and see what you get back.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm using the query correctly, but GET `/<indexname/location/Royal%20Leamington%20Spa?fielddata_fields=name` returns an identical document for both indexes.

Comment: No, what I meant is: `curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/locations/location/_search" -d'
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "_id": "Royal Leamington Spa"
        }
      }
    }
  }, 
  "fielddata_fields":["name"]
}'`

Comment: Pretty strange to see the id as `Royal Leamington Spa`. Why do you have it like this?

Comment: I can't remember why I did that. Could that be the underlying issue?

Comment: :) that was a curiosity of mine. Haven't seen so far IDs specified as a regular text and I find it unusual.